# installing two apps that have same bundle identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod

I develop an app and then i made two version of it. one is free and second is paid. Now i want to use same bundle identifier two install both app on one iphone, or ipod. how can i do this. and will it work fine when i submit it two app store.

What method developer used in their free version and paid version? Do they use Different bundle identifiers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iOS Developer portal will not let you create two apps with the same Bundle Identifier. Each app on the AppStore must have a different Bundle Identifier so you will definitely have problems if you try to submit it to the store.

Moreover, I believe XCode will erase the previous app on your device when you try to run a new one with the same bundle identifier.

My suggestion is to use something like com.yourcompany.myproductlite for your free version. Of course this means you will not be able to share GameCenter data and so on...

Another way is to make your App free and use In-App purchase to have people unlock the full version.

Answer (score 2):

Use wild card bundle indentifier .ie. put a "*"in ur bundle identifier