# Two apps that have same owner on appstore but different bundle idenfier ,can they have same idfv

Tags: ios, iphone

I have two apps on appstore but they have different base bundle idenfier.e.g com.mycom.myapp and second is com.mycom1.myapp2 now can these apps have same idfv(identifierforvendor) on same device or not.

Comment: This post has some detail regarding about your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528978/identifierforvendor

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have 2 different bundle id's.

A vendor is identified by the first two dot separated fields. So com.a.app1 and com.a.app2 have same vendor (com.a) but com.b.app3 has a different vendor (com.b)

The iOS Developer portal will not let you create two apps with the same Bundle Identifier. Each app on the AppStore must have a different Bundle Identifier so you will definitely have problems if you try to submit it to the store.
For further details read this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

[installing two apps that have same bundle identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470535/installing-two-apps-that-have-same-bundle-identifier)

[Bundle identifier and app name in iPhone & iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549902/bundle-identifier-and-app-name-in-iphone-ipad)

[Can two application have the same Bundle Name, but different Bundle Identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160808/can-two-application-have-the-same-bundle-name-but-different-bundle-identifier)

Answer (score 0):

No . identifierForVendor is Unique device and app wise and It will be change if your removed app from device and again install . Please check below url for more -

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor